# Java ProcessBuilder.start() taking considerably longer than executing in a terminal

Tags: java, multithreading, process, clearcase

I have a GUI that starts a new thread (`getFilesThread`) when the user clicks a button. This thread invokes the `start()` method of an instance of my `ClearCaseProcess` class below (my organization won't let me use the ClearCase Java API), and when the process(es) ends, it updates the GUI.

```
private static class ClearCaseProcess {

private ArrayList<String> stdout = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> stderr = new ArrayList<>();
private ProcessBuilder pb = null;

public ClearCaseProcess(ArrayList<String> commands, String dir) throws IOException {
    pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
    pb.directory(new File(dir));
}

public void start() throws IOException {
    long minStart = System.nanoTime();

    Process process = pb.start();

    Thread sout = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String outLine = "";

            try {
                while ((outLine = out.readLine()) != null) {
                    stdout.add(outLine);
                    System.out.println(outLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    };
    sout.start();

    Thread serr = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));

            String errLine = "";

            try {
                while ((errLine = err.readLine()) != null) {
                    stderr.add(errLine);
                    System.err.println(errLine);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    serr.start();

    try {
        process.waitFor();
        long execTime = System.nanoTime() - minStart;
        System.out.println("Process '" + description + "' took " + execTime);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

}
```

`getFiles()` needs to gather data from four different `ClearCaseProcess`es. I plan to run these concurrently in four threads. Each of these threads has two associated auxiliary threads to consume `stdout` and `stderr`, as shown above. I'm assuming that this will be faster than running ClearCase four times sequentially. For now, however, I'm testing just one ClearCase call.

My issue is that the time elapsed between calling `Process.start()` and the return of `Process.waitFor()` is much longer (about 5 minutes) than the time elapsed when I run the same ClearCase command on the terminal (about 1.5 minutes). I suspect that my loops reading stdout and stderr are the culprits, because even my print statements are slow to produce output in NetBeans' console.  How can I speed this up?

Comment: Have you tried running the Java application outside of Netbeans?

Comment: Hmm, strange. Assuming that you are first concerned about runtime ... have you tried to **not** read anything from those streams? Just fire the process command and measure execution time? To *prove* that the streams give the overhead?

Comment: @GhostCat, if the process is actually emitting anything into its output and/or error stream then it is *essential* for the Java program to consume it, otherwise the external process might never terminate at all.

Comment: If the external process is producing a large amount of output, then it may be that the problem is related to *storing* all that output in your two lists.  You could consider redirecting the output to a file or to the null device, or else just dropping everything you read on the floor.

Comment: Are you using that in a dynamic view? Are you using setview? What version of ClearCase are you using? On which OS?

Comment: It looks like NetBeans was adding the overhead. I ran it without the consuming stdout/stderr threads, and the times were almost identical. Running with the threads increased the time only sightly.

Thanks! I thought that as long as I wasn't debugging, NetBeans wouldn't cause that much overhead!

Answer (score 2):

For my specific case, running (not debugging) inside the IDE was causing the overhead.

When ran from the console (`java -jar myExecutable.jar`), the times were very close.
Noobish mistake.